# Exclude select menu form onclick onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using DataTables (https://datatables.net) where I have clickable rows. Here is my code for that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let city = document.getElementById("cityselect").value;

    var table = $('#resdatatable').DataTable();

    $('#resdatatable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {

        var data = table.row( this ).data().id;

         alert ("clicked!");

    } );
} );
```

In those clickable rows, I have a select box that onchange calls a function. Looks like this:

```
<select id ="resstatus1" onchange="changeResStatus(1)" data-previousvalue="Confirmed">
```

The issue I am having is that in Chrome (not Safari) when the select box is clicked on, I get an alert. I need to make it so clicking the select box doesn't trigger the alert. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code for the onclick function?

Comment: Just remove the `alert ("clicked!");`?

Comment: @JimmyAdaro Thats why I asked for the rest of the code, because I don't know if he wants the alert for another reason or not.

Comment: I'm sorry, the actual function runs Ajax code to access a MySQL database via PHP. I just took that out and replaced it with "alert ("clicked!");" to simplify the question. I want the row to alert, but I DO NOT WANT the select box, which is inside the row to alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it this way and it works:

```
$('#resdatatable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
if($(e.target).is('select')){
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
};
```

The other ways mentioned broke the the entire click function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by checking the target element. I made up a little, generic fiddle that you can test. I believe this is what you are trying to do. Now when you click on the select element, you won't get that alert message, but if you click the tr anywhere else, you'll see the alert message.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7136cyhp/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // let city = document.getElementById("cityselect").value;
  // var table = $('#resdatatable').DataTable();

  $('table td').on('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target !== this) {
      return;
    } else {
      //var data = table.row( this ).data().id;
      alert ("clicked!");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
}

tr {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id="test">
        <option value="">1</option>
        <option value="">2</option>
        <option value="">3</option>
        <option value="">4</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Oddly enough while it works in the example, it breaks the clickable rows in the Data Table. Is there another way?

Comment: @Tony What do you mean when you say it breaks? The layout gets messed up? No click event fires? It could be that I'm using a different selector in that code.

Comment: No click event fires

Answer (score 0):

A simple and clean way to achieve this is using the [stopPropagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) function on the event - this prevents an event bubbling up the DOM tree, so event handlers on parent elements are not notified of the event. If you apply this to clicks on the `select`, then it won't trigger any events attached to the parent cells or rows etc.

Demo:

```js
$('#resdatatable tbody').on('click', 'select', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$('#resdatatable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(e) {
  alert("hello");
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="resdatatable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello, you can click this bit</td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option>Clicking this won't fire the event</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```